# Generics and BiPredicate with incorrect return type

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

While following a course for `Java 8` we're now onto the topic of `Generics` and `Lambda expressions`. We've been asked to make the following method `Generic` and not `String` only:

```
public static String betterString(String s1,String s2,IBetterString bs){
    if(bs.isBetter(s1, s2)){
        return s1;
    }else{
        return s2;
    }
}
```

What I made of this so far is the following:

```
public static <T> betterEllement(T s1, T s2, BiPredicate<T, T> bi) {
    if (bi.test(s1, s2)) {
        return s1;
    } else {
        return s2;
    }
}
```

But it appears that my `Return type` according to Intellij is incorrect. I don't really understand why that is, because I defined `<T>` as a return type for this method. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just a beginner and would like to understand why it's not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you return nothing using your method. `<T>` define it's a generic Type which is not known yet. That doesnt mean that you return it. You need to add another T which is the generic Type return value.

Its

```
public static <T> T betterEllement(T s1, T s2, BiPredicate<T, T> bi) {
    if (bi.test(s1, s2)) {
        return s1;
    } else {
        return s2;
    }
}
```

`<T>` can also be used if you know the return value but want to define generic arguments.

```
public static <T> String getStringTest(T test) { 
  if (test.getClass().isInstance(WhatEver.class)) { ....} 
  return "test"; 
}
```

You can see it perfectly using a generic Class.

```
class TestGeneric<T> {
    public T betterElement(T s1) { /** .. **/ return null; }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Keep in mind. T is just a placeholder. It can be any char or even a String but T is usually used since it is a generic (T)ype.